# How do I split or create a new column for a list of data in a dataframe?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-munging

[image]

Please have a look at the preview of the data in theimage. I would like to create 3 new columns i.e. Start, End, Density and create new row for each record in  these 3 columns.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `data.frame(start = c(...), end = c(...), density = c(...)`?

Comment: `as.data.frame(data1[["first_paint.histogram.bin"]][1])`?

Comment: In your list, does the length of start, end and density match? If so , just do `data.frame(mylist)`

Comment: Also,  please do not post data or code as an image.  Why?  Please read [Why not upload images of code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4752675)

Comment: @zx8754 Sure, I'm new here. I will frame the questions in a better way next time. Thanks.

Comment: @jyr I'm not able to manipulate the data inside this list.

Comment: Great, then please post reproducible example `dput(head(mydata))`. And provide expected output.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with comments above you can converse `list` into the `data.frame` as below:

```
# simulation of data.frame with one row and one cell with histogram
z <- hist(rnorm(1000))
z$start <- z$breaks[-length(z$breaks)]
z$end <- z$breaks[-1]
z[c("mids", "xname", "breaks", "equidist", "counts")] <- NULL
names_z <- names(z)
attributes(z) <- NULL
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, x = I(list((z))))

# Conversion of list to dataframe
setNames(as.data.frame(unlist(df["x"], recursive = FALSE)), names_z)
```

Output:

```
   density start  end
1    0.012  -3.0 -2.5
2    0.042  -2.5 -2.0
3    0.082  -2.0 -1.5
4    0.182  -1.5 -1.0
5    0.288  -1.0 -0.5
6    0.354  -0.5  0.0
7    0.418   0.0  0.5
8    0.300   0.5  1.0
9    0.172   1.0  1.5
10   0.088   1.5  2.0
11   0.050   2.0  2.5
12   0.012   2.5  3.0
```